# matplotlib plot does not show up even though I can save the plot as png file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am running on a mac from command line with virtualenv setup. I pip installed matplotlib and numpy. When I do the following in the python command line prompt:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
N = 5
ind = np.arange(N)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
menStd =   (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
width = 0.35
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r', yerr=menStd)
plt.savefig('myfilename.png') # this works
plt.show() #this does not
```

So `plt.show()` would pop up a white window like this

[image: white blank window]

without any content. However, I was able to save the plot as `png` file. Please help me.

====update====

If I run with the following

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.use('MacOSX')
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/myuser/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/Users/myuser/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 63, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)
  File "/Users/myuser/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 17, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _macosx
RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other backends. If you are using (Ana)Conda please install python.app and replace the use of 'python' with 'pythonw'. See 'Working with Matplotlib on OSX' in the Matplotlib FAQ for more information.
```

My mac is Mojave 10.14.6. Python version is

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:55:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: @JohanC leaving that out has the same effect. No plot.

Comment: How do you run your program? To get graphical output, running from inside an IDE such as Pycharm might help.

Comment: am just running from command line. let me add this detail.

Comment: What about ```matplotlib.use('MacOSX')```?

Comment: I run your code on macOS Catalina and got the output

Comment: @PéterLeéh no luck there. Please see my edit above

Comment: @DavidS please see my updated info.